# Why is does this function not write to the file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a program that generates random float random values from 0 to 1 and if the number equals "1.0 or 0.0" then it writes a "1" to another file and stops executing. Otherwise, if the "x" exceeds the "i" it then writes a "0" to the file but, my program just keeps running and doesn't write anything to the .txt file even though the .txt file exist

```
def main():
    i = 0
    x = 100
    while i < x:
        print(num.generate_number())
        if num in [1.0, 0.0]:
            print(f'The number {num} has been printed')
            f.write('1')
            return 0
        elif i == x:
            f.write("0")
            return main()
```

Comment: There's nothing to break out of the `while` loop. The values of i and x are not changing, so it is going to run forever.

Comment: Why do you even need the while loop here? You can just generate the random numbers and write + close the files based on the condition.

Comment: you never increment your i.

Comment: why the recursion?

Answer (score -1):

First you need to open your file in write/append mode.

```
def main():
    i = 0
    x = 100
    while i < x:
        print(num.generate_number())
        if num in [1.0, 0.0]:
            print(f'The number {num} has been printed')
            # 'w' - for rewrite, 'a' - for append
            with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
                f.write('1')
            return 0
        elif i == x:
            # 'w' - for rewrite, 'a' - for append
            with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
                f.write("0")
            return main()
```